# Multithreading and Selenium

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to open a set of links in different WebChrome drivers (`atcThread[]`) as fast as possible. I tried implementing `ExecutorService` but realized that the initial execution of the threads are sequential. Is there a way I could open up the links in parallel to be more faster. Thanks!

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ATC {
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);

    public void startThreads() {
        for (int i = 0; i < Captcha.x; i++) {
            executor.execute(new ATCpool(i, Generator.links[i]));
        }
    }

    private final class ATCpool implements Runnable{

        public ATCpool(int x, String link){
            Generator.atcThread[x].get(link);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me you get this behavior because you call the method `get(String url)` in the constructor of your class `ATCpool` instead of calling it into the `run` method to delegate its call to the thread pool as you expect.

Simply change your class `ATCpool` for something like this:

```
private final class ATCpool implements Runnable {

    private final int x;
    private final String link;

    ATCpool(int x, String link){
        this.x = x;
        this.link = link;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Will be called asynchronously by a thread of the thread pool
        Generator.atcThread[x].get(link);
    }
}
```